# Free-JQGrid: On Inline edit, the height of frozen columns is not matching with other columns

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am starting a new screen where I am using [this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/FontAwesome4Large-borderlessOnHover2-frozen.htm) example. Here I see the height of cells are distracting when I try to edit a row. Can anyone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the bug report. I committed [the fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/eef41f78dfdbf4b68b54b26d8163333d5085589c) of the problem to GitHub. Now [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/FontAwesome4Large-borderlessOnHover2-frozen.htm) works correctly.

Comment: You are Welcome. And Thanks a lot to you for a quick turnaround. Appreciate it!

Comment: @Sudhir: It's important that all found bugs will be reported. If one have the demo, which reproduces the problem, then I can fix the problem very quickly in the most cases.